# Uniqueness of Spinor representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Consider the group $\text{Spin}(n)$ with $n$ even, i.e. the double cover of $SO(n)$, with Lie group homomorphism $\lambda:\text{Spin}(n)\rightarrow SO(n)$. We know that the spin group admits a faithful representation on $\mathbb{C}^N$ for some $N$ induced by the isomorphism:

$$\mathbb{C}\text{l}(n)\cong \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N)$$

where $\mathbb{C}\text{l}(n)$ is the standard complex Clifford algebra of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Denote this representation by $\kappa$, and further recall that a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ acts on $\psi\in\mathbb{C}^n$ via the composition of the canonical injection $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\text{l}(n)\cong\text{Cl}(n)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ with the above isomorphism. Then $\kappa$ satisfies the property:
$$
\kappa(g)\cdot(x\cdot \psi)=(\lambda(g)\cdot x)\cdot (\kappa(g)\cdot \psi)
$$

My question is then this, does the above property uniquely determine spin representation up to isomorphism? More concretely, if $\rho:\text{Spin}(n)\rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^N)$ is a faithful representation which satisfies the above property, do we have that $\rho$ and $\kappa$ are related by a conjugation map, i.e. does there exist an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^N$ such that:

$$f(\kappa(g)\cdot \psi)=\rho(g)\cdot f(\psi)$$

I am asking because in the case of $n=4$, we have that $N=4$, and there are two ways I know of to obtain a faithful representation of $\text{Spin}(n)$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$. The first is the way outlined above, i.e. by making use of the isomorphism between the Clifford algebra and the endomorphism algebra. The other is to identify $\text{Spin}(n)$ with $SU(2)\times SU(2)$, which then acts naturally on $\mathbb{C}^4$ by multiplying with block diagonal matrices. both representations satisfy the above property, and I believe that they should be the same representation since many authors use the latter representation when discussing the spin representation in the case of $n=4$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451683/uniqueness-of-spinor-representation

Comment: **Every** representation has the property you mention. Let's be explicit with all our $\kappa$'s: $$\kappa(g)\cdot(\kappa(x)\cdot\psi) = \kappa(\lambda(g)\cdot x)\cdot(\kappa(g)\cdot\psi).$$ This is just a consequence of $\lambda(g)\cdot x = gxg^{-1}$: $$\kappa(g)\cdot(\kappa(x)\cdot\psi) = \kappa(gx)\cdot\psi = \kappa(gxg^{-1}g)\cdot\psi = \kappa((\lambda(g)\cdot x)g)\cdot\psi = \kappa(\lambda(g)\cdot x)\cdot(\kappa(g)\cdot\lambda).$$

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I don’t think this is true, it only works when the representation of $\text{Spin}$ is the restriction of the representation of the whole Clifford algebra no?

Comment: @Chris Are you saying when $\lambda$ is a restriction of $\kappa$? Then no, that is not necessary. We've embedded $\mathbb R^n$ in $\mathbb C\mathrm l(n)$ canonically, which means we can multiply vectors with other Clifford numbers. I assume that $\mathrm Spin(n) \subseteq \mathrm{Cl}(n)$ by definition (and also canonically $\mathrm{Cl}(n) \subseteq \mathbb C\mathrm l(n)$ based on your definition of the latter); the standard definition of $\mathrm Spin(n)$ naturally gives $\lambda$ the form $\lambda(g)\cdot x = gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: The **only** thing I do after that in my first comment is apply the definition of a left action. Now, you could do something silly like define $\lambda$ based on an algebra isomorphic but not equal to $\mathrm{Cl}(n)$ or by applying some automorphism of $\mathrm{Cl}(n)$, but why would you?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Suppose that $rho$ is another representation of $\text{Spin}(n)$ that is not the restriction of the isomorphism of the Clifford algebra. Then how do you write $\rho(g)\cdot \kappa(x)=\kappa(g\cdot x)$?

Comment: @Chris You don't and I don't write that anywhere.

Comment: @Chris Ah, I made a typo that is maybe what you're referring to? The last $\lambda$ in my first comment should be a $\psi$: $$\kappa(g)\cdot(\kappa(x)\cdot\psi) = \kappa(gx)\cdot\psi = \kappa(gxg^{-1}g)\cdot\psi = \kappa((\lambda(g)\cdot x)g)\cdot \psi = \kappa(\lambda(g)\cdot x)\cdot(\kappa(g)\cdot\color{red}\psi).$$

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff in your first equality you write $\kappa(g)\cdot( \kappa(x)\cdot \psi)=\kappa(gx)\cdot \psi$. This seems to hinge on the fact that the representation of the spin group is essentially the same as the one for the Clifford algebra

Comment: @Chris That's just the definition of a representation/action. It's a homomorphism.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff right, but only if the representation of the spin group is the restriction of the Clifford algebra representation. If you choose a different representation that’s not the necessarily the same representation, how can you write that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147607/discussion-between-nicholas-todoroff-and-chris).

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the question is: for fixed $\kappa : \mathbb C\mathrm l(n) \cong \mathrm{End}(\mathbb C^N)$ does the equation
$$
  f(g)\cdot(\kappa(x)\cdot\psi) = \kappa(\lambda(g)\cdot x)\cdot(f(g)\cdot\psi)
$$
for all $g \in \mathrm{Spin(n)}$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $\psi \in \mathbb C^N$, and $\lambda(g)\cdot x = gxg^{-1}$ imply that $f = \kappa|_{\mathrm{Spin(n)}}$?

The answer is *yes*. First, rewrite as
$$
  f(g)\kappa(x) = \kappa(gxg^{-1})f(g)
$$
and apply $\kappa^{-1}$ to get
$$
  g'x = gxg^{-1}g',\quad g' = \kappa^{-1}(f(g)).
$$
Then we can write
$$
  Gx = xG,\quad G = g^{-1}g'.
$$
Because $\mathrm{Cl}(n)$ is generated by $\mathbb R^n$ this means that $G$ is in the center of $\mathrm{Cl}(n)$; but because $n$ is even that means that $G$ is a scalar. So there is some $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $g' = ag$. But we have to have $(1)' = 1$, so $a = 1$ and $g' = g$. In other words, $f = \kappa|_{\mathrm{Spin}(n)}$.